# Changing image on click

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have placed an Image as a button in my App and I want to change the Image on clicking the button and If I leave it has to regain its original Image. Is it possible in phone 7?

Comment: That's very possible.  Are you familiar with WPF/Silverlight?

Comment: no,am new to the technology.jus give me sme idea so i can catch up.

Comment: If you want to get yourself familiarized with everything on the WP7, there's a free e-book [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx).

Comment: thank u benjer i hav that book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add two namespaces

```
using System.Windows.Resources;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```

create two events for mouse enter and mouse leave

```
private void btn_back_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri myfile = new Uri("image.png", UriKind.Relative);
        StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(myfile);
        BitmapImage myimage = new BitmapImage(myfile);
        myimage.SetSource(resourceInfo.Stream);
        btn_back.Source = myimage;
    }
    private void btn_back_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri myfile = new Uri("image.png.png", UriKind.Relative);
        StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(myfile);
        BitmapImage myimage = new BitmapImage(myfile);
        myimage.SetSource(resourceInfo.Stream);
        btn_back.Source = myimage;
    }
```

And the xaml file is

```
      <Image Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="17" x:Name="btn_back" Source="/NewUIChanges;component/Images/back_normal.png" Stretch="Fill"  MouseLeftButtonUp="img_cnvstop_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseEnter="btn_back_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btn_back_MouseLeave" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your button a Click event handler and your image a name, i.e.:

```
<Button Click="ImageButton_Click" ...>
    <Button.Content>
        <Image Name="Image" ImageSource="ImageSource.jpg" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

then in the event handler

```
private void ImageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Image.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri("NewImageSource.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

When you exit the app, it either get's tombstoned (meaning it basically shuts down and loses all information except what's saved) if you navigate somewhere else or completely shuts down if you press the back button, and either of those will reset the image to its original state.

Comment: how u placed an image in a button? i tnk we can only set background of a button?and can the button regain to its original image after the click event?

Comment: See my edit for the first part.  As for the second, there are many ways you can implement that.  I depends on what exactly you want to happen, though....

Comment: i tnk u misunderstood.i ve placed an image(that looks like button).i hvnt placed button bcoz if click a button it changes to white color and regain to its original color.so i placed an image and when i click it,it should blink.is it possible.

Comment: Ah, yeah it's possible.  You can either go the route of using a button (which you customize so it changes images instead of turning white) or handle the event when your image gets touch input.  That book tells you how to do the latter starting on page 52.